# Override DEFINE in PigUnit

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, apache-pig

In my pig script I use java UDFs where production data is handled. I would like to override that with Mock UDF classes where I will have my dummy implementation. I have DEFINE statements in my pig script which define invocation of a specific Java UDF class. Can I override the DEFINE statement in PigUnit to make it invoke the mock class?

```
DEFINE InvokeActual mypackage.function.ActualFunction();
```

should be replaced with

```
DEFINE InvokeActual mypackage.function.TestFunction();
```

If this is possible it can solve most of my problems faced with unit testing pig scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I see two scenarios:

1. I would try to export DEFINE methods to separate script and use [importing macros](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/cont.html#import-macros). Then you can change DEFINEs when it is unit testing or real use.
2. You can create the mock jar with same methods.

An obvious one is that if you repeat DEFINE InvokeActual then mapping to java method is overwritten but I guess you don't want to have separate pig script  for testing.

Comment: I like the idea 1. Thanks. I was looking for solution where we can replace DEFINE statement directly in pig script.

Comment: Let me know if it worked and please accept an answer, thanks!